# executing a makefile in many child directories with a linux csh script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, makefile, csh

I am trying to write a csh script which will execute a makefile in child directories when present. So far I have this:

`find -maxdepth 2 -name 'Makefile' -print -execdir make \;`

The issue I'm facing is that I get the following error when I try to run it:

`find: The current directory is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove the current directory from your $PATH (that is, remove "." or leading or trailing colons)`

I cannot reasonably change the $PATH variable in this case. Any ideas on a workaround.

Many thanks and happy coding

Comment: Don't use `csh` ; read the famous [C-shell considered harmful](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot). Switch to a better shell: `bash`, standardized Posix shell, [zsh](http://zsh.org/), ....

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with `make` or `csh`.  The problem is with `find` and nothing else.

Comment: Ya I would like to use bash - personally I am more comfortable with it but everything else so far has been done using csh (recently joined and can't change much now). I also think that MadScientist is right when he says that it is related to find and not csh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-execdir` flag is a feature of GNU find, and the way it's implemented is to throw that error and refuse to proceed if the situation it describes is detected.  There's no option in `find` to avoid that error.  So, you can either fix `PATH` (you can do that just for the `find` command itself:

```
 PATH=<fixed-path> find -maxdepth 2 -name 'Makefile' -print -execdir make \;
```

) or else don't use `-execdir` as described by Basile.

Err... actually that's POSIX sh syntax.  Does `csh` support that?  I haven't used `csh` in so long that I can't remember, and honestly it's such a bad shell that I can't be bothered to go look :-p :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
  find -maxdepth 2 -name 'Makefile' \
       -exec sh -c "make -C $(dirname {})" \;
```

or (using `sh` syntax)

```
  for m in  Makefile */Makefile */*/Makefile ; do
     if [ -f "$m" ]; then 
        make -C $(dirname $m)
     fi
  done
```